# How to open a custom made tab and its div using an external URL or link?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, parameter-passing

```
<section class="ask-librarian-from">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row split-area">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-block active" id="libtab1">
          <div class="form-title">
            content1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block " id="libtab2">
          <div class="form-title">
            content 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block " id="libtab3">
          <div class="form-title">
            content 3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block " id="libtab4">
          <div class="form-title">
            content 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="tab-wrap mCustomScrollbar">
          <div class="vertical-tabs right-align-tab  scrollContainer" id="verticalTabsScroll" data-mcs-theme="dark">
            <a href="#libtab1" class="tab_item active">
              content tab 1
            </a>
            <a href="#libtab2" class="tab_item ">
              content tab 2 
            </a>
            <a href="#libtab3" class="tab_item ">
              content tab 3
            </a>
            <a href="#libtab4" class="tab_item ">
              content tab 4
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I just want to active a tab using a URL or link. That is when I go to **www.mydomain.com/page/#libtab2**,  it automatically open and activate the 'libtab2' tab and its content and hide all others tab's contents.

Comment: The anchoring should work using `#libtab2` on the anchor tag. Have you applied any javascript to show that tab?

Comment: yea just to show and hide the items. actually at a time  it only active and shows one tab an its content. @tshimkus


   $('.ask-librarian-from .vertical-tabs a').click( function(e){
      var selectedTab = $(this).attr('href');
     
      $('.ask-librarian-from .vertical-tabs a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      
      $('.ask-librarian-from').find('.form-block').removeClass('active');
      $('.ask-librarian-from').find(selectedTab).addClass('active');

         e.preventDefault();
   });

Comment: It can definitely be done, and your template already has some support for it, but the provided code doesn't have enough to help you. I imagine the code for that shows tabs on click works, right? Would you mind sharing a link?

Answer (score 1):

How about this code on load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ask-librarian-from .vertical-tabs a').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href]="' + window.location.hash + '"').addClass('active');
    $('.ask-librarian-from').find('.form-block').removeClass('active');
    $('.ask-librarian-from').find(window.location.hash).addClass('active');
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<section class="ask-librarian-from">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row split-area">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-block active" id="libtab1">
          <div class="form-title">
            content1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block " id="libtab2">
          <div class="form-title">
            content 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block " id="libtab3">
          <div class="form-title">
            content 3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block " id="libtab4">
          <div class="form-title">
            content 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="tab-wrap mCustomScrollbar">
          <div class="vertical-tabs right-align-tab  scrollContainer" id="verticalTabsScroll" data-mcs-theme="dark">
            <button class="tab_item active" id="tab1" onClick="myFunction(this.id)">
              content tab 1
            </button>
            <button class="tab_item " id="tab2" onClick="myFunction(this.id)">
              content tab 2 
            </button>
            <button class="tab_item " id="tab3" onClick="myFunction(this.id)">
              content tab 3
            </button>
            <button class="tab_item " id="tab4" onClick="myFunction(this.id)">
              content tab 4
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<script>
  function myFunction(clicked_id) {
    var libtab1 = document.getElementById("libtab1");
    var libtab2 = document.getElementById("libtab2");
    var libtab3 = document.getElementById("libtab3");
    var libtab4 = document.getElementById("libtab4");

    if (clicked_id === "tab1") {
      libtab1.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("tab1").className = "active";
    } else {
      libtab2.style.display = "none";
      libtab3.style.display = "none";
      libtab4.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (clicked_id === "tab2") {
      libtab2.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("tab2").className = "active";
    } else {
      libtab1.style.display = "none";
      libtab3.style.display = "none";
      libtab4.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (clicked_id === "tab3") {
      libtab3.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("tab3").className = "active";
    } else {
      libtab1.style.display = "none";
      libtab2.style.display = "none";
      libtab4.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (clicked_id === "tab4") {
      libtab4.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("tab4").className = "active";
    } else {
      libtab1.style.display = "none";
      libtab2.style.display = "none";
      libtab3.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can implement JavaScript for displaying/hiding the specific content of an item. When you click on the Tab1 it will display the property of Tab1 and hide the other tab's content. Also for setting a new class you can use this JS property "document.getElementById("put_your_id").className = "put_your_class_name";". It will set the class name of that particular ID. Here I shared the full source code for your better help.

Comment: Good try, but your code is too long for a simple operation. Try and make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger method of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href]="' + window.location.hash + '"').trigger('click');  
)
```